# How to sort loop based on response value from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So below is a small structure how I loop items, I want to sort them in my loop from by amount of members to smallest, instead of it being randomly displayed? How should I approach this? Also, if loop contains only 2 elements, how can I set display div to none?

```
    <% for item in @items %>

<%= item.name %>
<%= item.members %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```rb
<% if @items.size > 2 %>
  <div>
    <% @items.sort_by { |item| item.members.size }.each do |item| %>
      <%= item.name %>
      <%= item.members %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In the `sort_by` thing I get `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`

Comment: Is members a value or a model, named members?  If it is just a value, then just remove ".size".